# Cobertura plugin for grails 2.3.9 does not work

Tags: grails, cobertura

I have a grails 2.3.7 project that is using cobertura plugin, it works perfectly fine.

But when I upgraded to 2.3.9 it stopped working.

This is some of the relevant parts of the stacktrace that I get.

```
Error Cobertura: Error reading from object stream.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.PackageData
...
Cobertura: Coverage data file /home/user/cobertura.ser either does not exist or is not readable.  Creating a new data file.
```

Comment: did you tried cleaning the project with grails clean?

Comment: @luisZavaleta Yes I did, numerous times.

Comment: Check the version of the plugins in your BuildConfig file, some plugins have parameters are relative to the version, for example:    

 -- runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"  --

will work with grails 2.2 but not with grails 2.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the info page of `grails-coverage-plugin` current version (2.0.3-1):

```
This plugin will generate code coverage reports using Cobertura.

 Currently Grails Forked mode is not supported.
```

You should to remove forked options from `Build.config`. Removing only the test option is enough.

Comment: I already tried removing the test fork mode but the error still persists. Is this an issue on grails 2.3.9?

Comment: Try commenting all `grails.project.fork` section on `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now. Update to the latest version.